# Do scanner room range upgrades stack?

Tags: subnautica

I installed the scanner room range and speed updates in my scanner room, but I have two more slots for upgrades. If I add two more range upgrades do they stack with the existing one?

I tried adding them but it's really not clear if it made a difference or not. The map in the scanner room doesn't look any larger...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, according to the [Scanning Room wiki page](http://subnautica.wikia.com/wiki/Scanner_Room), upgrades of the same type will stack and increase their overall effectiveness:

> The Scanner Room will also scan for nearby resources, identifying them as red blips on the central hologram. It has a base scanning range of 300 meters and max of 500 meters. The scanner can only search for one resource type at a time and has a base time of 14 seconds, but the searching speed and range can be increased to take 2 seconds at max with the Scanner Room Range Upgrade and Scanner Room Speed Upgrade; **you can have more of the same upgrade in the scanner room to extend the range and speed even more.**